# Use an array as a Scala foldLeft accumulator

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I am trying to use a foldLeft on an array. Eg:

```
var x = some array 
x.foldLeft(new Array[Int](10))((a, c) => a(c) = a(c)+1)
```

This refuses to compile with the error found Int(0) required Array[Int].

Comment: are you aware that `some calculation` must evaluate to a `Array[Int]` and that `new Array[Int](10)` creates an array of 10 elements? It would be helpful if you show the rest of the code. Or at least the intention.

Comment: `a(c) = a(c)+1` has type `Unit` while you need `Array[Int]`. What exactly do you want to achieve with your code?

Comment: Some array is a large array containing integers from 0 to 9. I want to count how many of each there are.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order to use `foldLeft` in what you want to do, and following your style, you can just return the same accumulator array in the computation like this:

```
val ret = a.foldLeft(new Array[Int](10)) {
      (acc, c) => acc(c) += 1; acc
    }
```

Alternatively, since your numbers are from 0 to 9, you can also do this to achieve the same result:

```
val ret = (0 to 9).map(x => a.count(_ == x))
```

Answer (score 2):

Assignment in Scala does not return a value (but instead Unit) so your expression that is supposed to return the Array[Int] for the next step returns Unit which does not work.

You would have to use a block and return the array in the end like this:

```
x.foldLeft(new Array[Int](10)) { (a, c) => 
  a(c) = a(c)+1
  a
}
```

Comment: an obvious clarification, is that if you don't assign the outcome of `foldLeft` to something, it will be lost. But just in case.